# como hacer migrate en AWS con Django

Tags: python, django

estoy haciendo un deploy en AWS con Django, el deploy se subio correctamente, ahora no se como hacer el migrate, puse un archivo db-migrate.config dentro del .ebextensions en mi proyecto de django con el siguiente codigo :

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: irsmain.settings
```

pero me sale el siguiente error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no se hace la migracion, al momento de abrir la pagina me sale lo siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que me imagino que sucede por la falta de la base de datos, alguien tiene una idea de como hacer el migrate de otra manera o que estoy haciendo mal?, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, use este comando dentro de mi db-migrate.config

```
container_commands:
    01_migrate:
        command: "$PYTHONPATH/python manage.py migrate --noinput"
```

los espacios son importantes, al parecer AWS los toma en cuenta, hay que identar correctamente